# obj and $this returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the anchor text of a link, and change the href of it via the id, here's my javascript:

```
$('.like_status').click(function(event) { // bind function to submit event of form
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(responseText) {
            $(this).attr("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/unlike_status/" + $(this).attr('id'));
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).text('Unlike');

        }
    });
});
```

I have tried using obj but that doesn't work too, here's my href:

```
<span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>&nbsp;<a class="like_status" id="<?php echo System::escape($status->timeline_status_id); ?>" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/like_status/<?php echo System::escape($status->timeline_status_id); ?>"> <?php echo System::translate("Like"); ?></a>&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: `this` inside ajax success is not refers to dom object, it refers to xhr object

Comment: You'd need to capture the jQuery element to use inside the Ajax success function.

Comment: Sorry, how can I fix this, I am still learning to do this stuff :(

Comment: either set `context` or cache it as `var $this=$(this)`

Answer (score 2):

Because of scope and closures, I recommend creating varibles at the beginning of functions instead of relying on `this`:

```
// Using the more recent ON method instead of the
// "old-school" .click method
$('.like_status').on('click', function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $link.attr('href'),
        success: function(responseText) {
            $link.attr("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/unlike_status/" + $link.attr('id'));
            alert($link.attr('id'));
            $link.text('Unlike');

        }
    });
});
```

I prefix my jQuery objects with $ and although negliable in this instance, by settings a variable to the jQuery call `$(this)` I don't have to call it everytime somewhere else.

I'd recommend reading [Explaining JavaScript scope and closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) which covers the basis of why you are experiencing this problem.

Comment: Neither scopes nor closures have anything to do with `this` (pun intended). Scopes are about source code whereas `this` is a runtime issue. The article does not explain the OP's problem: Every function has its own binding for `this` at runtime. But you could easily bind the `success` handler's `this` to the same value as that of the `click` handler. Something that wouldn't be possible if the problem was about scopes or closures. The preferred solution is to use an arrow function, provided it's supported by the environment.

Comment: Then it's quite odd that `this` changes when it is referenced within an object and is no longer the link (in his case) but the object it is in (within the scope of the object he created).  I would definitely yeild this is not a closure issue and I only added closure to the discussion because it has similar traits as a scope thus a good learning experience to combine the two in this learning example.

Comment: _"Then it's quite odd that `this` changes when it is referenced within an object"_ - Well, no, that was exactly my point. The value of `this` can be changed at runtime, scope can't. Please mind that in JavaScript there's no such thing as _within an object_ or _scope of the object_. Any function can be attached to any object at any time and called independently of it nonetheless, leading to different values for `this`. The closure's characteristics, however, are not affected, neither is the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the DOM element using `event.target`

```
$('.like_status').click(function(event) { // bind function to submit event of form
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(event.target).attr('href'),
        success: function(responseText) {
            $(event.target).attr("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/unlike_status/" + $(event.target).attr('id'));
            alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
            $(event.target).text('Unlike');

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have suggested, add a reference to the element outside of your ajax function, and then use that reference in place of `$(this)`

```
$('.like_status').click(function(event) { // bind function to submit event of form
    event.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this); //add a reference
    $.ajax({
        url: $link.attr('href'),
        success: function(responseText) {
            $link.attr("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/unlike_status/" + $link.attr('id'));
            alert($link.attr('id'));
            $link.text('Unlike');

        }
    });
});
```